# Displaying data from stored procedures with multiple tables into textbox

Tags: database, vb.net, stored-procedures

```
SELECT 
    Login.LoginID, Student.[Student Name], Student.[Student address], Student.StudentID
FROM
    Login 
INNER JOIN
    Student ON Login.LoginID = Student.LoginID
WHERE
    (Login.username = @user) AND (Login.password = @pass)

RETURN
```

How do I display the Student Name, Student Address, StudentID, and LoginID into multiple textboxes?

Comment: you need to take a look at a tutorial; your question is, perhaps unintentionally, too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's and example of how to retrieve results from our stored procedure and assign returned columns to text boxes:

```
Function GetInfoForStudent(ByRef QueryName As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As DataTable
    Using Con As New SqlConnection
        Try
            Using OleCon As New SqlConnection
                Dim Connection As String = "MyConnectionString"
                Con.Open()
                Dim Cmd As SqlCommand = Con.CreateCommand()
                Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                Cmd.CommandText = QueryName
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", UserName)
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", Password)
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataTable()
                da.Fill(ds)
                Return ds
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using

End Function

Sub ShowStudentInfo()
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetInfoForStudent("MyStoredProcName", "MyUserName", "MyPasswword")
    ' Since (presumably) only one is returned
    With dt.Rows(0)
        ' Assign your text boxes 
        'LoginIDTextBox.Text = .Item("LoginID")
        'StudentNameTextBox.Text = .Item("Student Name")
        'StudentAddressTextBox.Text = .Item("Student address")
        'StudentIDTextBox.Text = .Item("StudentID")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough, but you can create a typed dataset with for your SP, which results in a table, then bind Student Name, Student Address, StudentID, and LoginID columns to 4 different TextBoxes, in designer: TextBox1->DataBindings->Text and choose your SP as datasource.