# Displaying saved Data onto textbox after saving it

Tags: database, vb.net, insert

How do I display out the data row of a table out on a textbox after saving it.

```
      Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.StudentBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LibraryDataSet)
        MsgBox("Student Info Added")
        Me.Close()
        frmLibrary.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: What value are you trying to display?  Are you trying to display a set of records or just one?  Please be more specific.

Comment: What i want to display is the row of the records

Comment: @Complete: The row of the records is a contradiction in terms since one record is one row. A DataSet can contain multiple tables, one table can contain multiple rows. A row can contain multiple columns. So what do you want to display?

Comment: the row that I had created above. Not really sure bout how to explain it but it's something like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9152637/1180498)